# can i call javascript code to close window from Ember button or link

Tags: javascript, ember.js

Sorry javascript/ember noob question, 
I have an Ember page with a link and a button. 
Is it possible when i click on either of them to call javascript code to close the browser tab in which the ember page is opened.

Comment: Have you tried to execute `window.close();` when clicking the button?

Comment: You can close a window if only you had opened it via ` window.open()`.

Comment: i didn't open the window using window.open(), its an ember web app, i transitioned to this page (using transitionTo method in the controller action) from a button click on a previous page. 
Is there any way i can close the browser tab in this case then.

Comment: Nope, AlbertoLasa's answer is correct. See the docs mentioned in his answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use 'window.close()' but you only could close the window if before it was open with the method window.open().

- https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Window/open
- https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Window/close

Answer (score 1):

> As of 2017, there is no way to close a web browser tab or window using
>   JavaScript. Modern security standards do not permit this behavior.

https://www.computerhope.com/issues/ch000178.htm

As you can read here, is a no more allowed behaviour by modern browsers